# Federate multiple IdP with OIDC to Azure B2C and authentication without user interaction

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are trying to use Azure B2C for a use case where we did not find much information. The idea is that several partners, each with their corresponding IdPs, will embed in their web and mobile applications our platform.

This platform can be consumed via API or via WebView, depending on the maturity of our partners' applications. Partners want to federate their IdPs with our Azure B2C with OIDC.

The problem comes with the user experience that we are proposing. The user is facing a double login with the same credentials. One time when entering the partner's app and a second time when entering the tab of our functionality inside the partner's app (our B2C redirecting by OIDC to the partner's IdP).

Is it possible to do this flow without the user re-entering his credentials inside each partner's app to access our services?